# Hide button after click outside

Tags: c#, button, hide

I feel that this question must have been asked many times before, but I can't find it. Sorry if I'm right.

The thing is that I have a X button like this at the corner of my application:

[image]

I have other confirmation button ( visible= false and enable= false) next to it. When I click on X button I set these properties to true and the button appears.

[image]

If now I click on it the form close. But here is my question. How can I hide the confirmation button and disable it again if I click on any other part of my application?

Probably is trivial. Sorry, I'm quite new in all of this.

Thank you very much for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dunno, maybe an event like this?

this.MouseClick += (sender, args) => { this.button1.Visible = false; };

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to add a [MessageFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.aspx) to your application that passively listens for click events and hides the Confirm button - Just search on IMessageFilter to find lots of articles about how to use it.

Note that there are a lot of other windows messages that you could use to disable the Confirm button (e.g. not just clicks, but keypresses, moving the window, etc), so you can use this to implement a comprehensive solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't use this for this but I will use it for keypresses and similar stuff